# Spinner don't want to remove from superview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a UIActivityIndicatorView so when I try to search in search bar, It will loading first before the data come in. I make the spinner in UIViewController extension for animating and remove the animating from the view. but somehow I can't figure it out why the view I want to remove is not removing, when I try to use break point. the function dismissLoading I create is not being called, why it happen? can someone help me. this is my code

```
fileprivate var containerView: UIView!

extension UIViewController {

    func showLoadingView() {
        containerView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(containerView)

        containerView.backgroundColor   = .systemBackground
        containerView.alpha             = 0.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { containerView.alpha = 0.8 }

        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
        containerView.addSubview(activityIndicator)

        activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }

    func dismissLoadingView() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            containerView.removeFromSuperview()
            containerView = nil
        }
    }
}

// This is my PhotosViewController 
extension PhotosViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, !searchText.isEmpty else {
            dataSource.data.value.removeAll()
            viewModel.isSearching.value = false
            return
        }

        photoName = searchText

        viewModel.isSearching.value = true
        showLoadingView()
        if let photoName = photoName {
            viewModel.getPhoto(query: photoName) { [weak self] error in
                self?.dismissLoadingView()
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try printing `self` along with the error inside and `getPhoto` tell me what you get.

Comment: @Frankenstein nothing has been print, I use breakpoint when try to print(self) and error

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing it disappear because you're adding a new instance of the container view and activity indicator every time the search query changes. If the query updates a second time before the first query has returned results, the reference to your first `containerView` will be reassigned to a new view instance.

If you attempt to fix this by checking if `containerView == nil` before presenting, you will also run into issues if you have multiple search results requests out, one returns, and then the loading view gets dismissed despite there being other requests out.

Comment: yes you right, when I try to checking like you suggest. the loading seem for awhile is dismissing than loading again in transparent background, and it's not stopping. how can remove after it?